# Campo de pesquisa em uma tabela com PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Criei um *frame* na intranet através do WordPress (php, MySQL) para listar os ramais dos funcionários da empresa. Ao clicar no *link* de ramais aparece uma tabela e a barra de rolagem para visualização da lista. Preciso criar um campo de busca (campo criado mas sem funcionalidade ainda) nessa página para que o usuário tenha a opção de ao invés de procurar pela lista quem ela quer, ela digite o nome da pessoa, clique em buscar e ao fazer isso a tabela se restrinja apenas as pessoas com o nome ou parte do nome correspondente ao digitado. Como fazer isso? 
Segue me código atual.

```
<!-- Campo para pesquisa -->
<input type="text" name="texto"  placeholder="Digite a pesquisa" />
<button type="submit">Buscar</button></div><br><br>

<?php
   $sql = "SELECT ramal, setor , coalesce (funcionario, setor) as funcionario FROM ramais ORDER BY funcionario asc";
   $dados = mysql_query($sql); 

   $linha = mysql_fetch_array($dados);
?>

<table class="lista-ramais">

<?php 
   $ramal = ($linha['ramal']);
   $setor = ($linha['setor']);
   $funcionario = ($linha['funcionario']);
   $classe = "";
   if ( $linha['ramal'] <> " " ) { $classe=" style='background:#E0DEFE'"; 
     echo "</table><br /><table class='lista-ramais'><tr><th " . $classe . ">Usuário</th><th " . $classe . ">Ramal</td> <th " . $classe . ">Setor</th></tr>";

     while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array($dados) ) {
        echo "<tr><td align=left>" . ucwords($linha['funcionario']) . "<br /></td><td>" . ucwords($linha['ramal']) . "</td> <td>" . ucwords($linha['setor']) . "</td></tr>";
     }
   }    
 ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente você não está usando o Wordpress para nada nessa página.

Então é só criar um filtro simples na sua query mysql:

```
<!-- Campo para pesquisa -->
<input type="text" name="texto"  placeholder="Digite a pesquisa" />
<button type="submit">Buscar</button></div><br><br>

<?php
   $sql = "SELECT ramal, setor , coalesce (funcionario, setor) as funcionario FROM ramais"; //inicio do sql
   $busca = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['texto']); //sanitiza e carrega os dados do form
   if (!empty($busca)) { 
        $sql .= " WHERE funcionario LIKE %" . $busca ."%";
   }
   $sql .= " ORDER BY funcionario asc"; //fim do sql. importante manter o espaço no início
   $dados = mysql_query($sql); 
   $linha = mysql_fetch_array($dados);
?>

<table class="lista-ramais">

<?php 
   $ramal = ($linha['ramal']);
   $setor = ($linha['setor']);
   $funcionario = ($linha['funcionario']);
   $classe = "";
   if ( $linha['ramal'] <> " " ) { $classe=" style='background:#E0DEFE'"; 
     echo "</table><br /><table class='lista-ramais'><tr><th " . $classe . ">Usuário</th><th " . $classe . ">Ramal</td> <th " . $classe . ">Setor</th></tr>";

     while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array($dados) ) {
        echo "<tr><td align=left>" . ucwords($linha['funcionario']) . "<br /></td><td>" . ucwords($linha['ramal']) . "</td> <td>" . ucwords($linha['setor']) . "</td></tr>";
     }
   }    
 ?>
</table>
```

Apesar de usar o `mysql_real_escape_string` para evitar injeções de SQL, o mais indicado é usar PDO para esse tipo de interação.